# Can not publish .NET Core 8 standalone exe

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-8.0, self-contained

I currently have the following problem.

I have a .NET Core 8 solution which contains 2 projects.

1. `Shared` <- Windows Forms App (publish with no errors)
2. `Client` <- Windows Forms App (publish with error - standlone exe and self contained)

Error:

> Unexpected error in the GenerateBundle task.
> Client \bin\Release\net8.0-windows\win-x64\app.publish\Shared.deps.json" could not be found.
>
> Dateiname: "\Client\bin\Release\net8.0-windows\win-x64\app.publish\Shared.deps.json"
>
> bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> bei System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> bei System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
> bei Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.IsAssembly(String path, Boolean& isPE)
> bei Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.InferType(FileSpec fileSpec)
> bei Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs)
> bei Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateBundle.ExecuteCore()
> bei Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
> bei Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskWithAssemblyResolveHooks.Execute()
> bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

The missing file `Shared.deps.json` is located in `<Removed>\Client\bin\Release\net8.0-windows\win-x64` and not the subfolder `app.publish`.

There are no other errors in the output. Starting the application inside Visual Studio in Debug and Release Mode works normally.

Used frameworks by both `.csproj`:

- Microsoft.NETCore.App
- Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms

The following Nuget packages are used in `Client.csproj`:

- Npgsql (8.0.1)
- System.Management (8.0.0)
- MaterialSkin.2 (2.31.)

Com references in `Client.csproj`:

- IWshRuntimeLibrary

The following Nuget packages are used in `Shared.csproj`:

- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (8.0.2)
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core (8.0.2)
- System.data.SQLite.Core (1.0.118)
- MaterialSkin.2 (2.31.)

`Client.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyName>ClientInstaller</AssemblyName>
        <ApplicationIcon>Resources/Icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Resources\Driver.exe" />
        <None Remove="Resources\NET.zip" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <COMReference Include="IWshRuntimeLibrary">
            <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
            <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
            <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
            <Guid>f935dc20-1cf0-11d0-adb9-00c04fd58a0b</Guid>
            <Lcid>0</Lcid>
            <Isolated>false</Isolated>
            <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
        </COMReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Driver.exe" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\InstallationFiles.zip" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Management" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Shared.csproj">
            <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be here.

Even googling didn't really get me any further. I just need a way to publish the software as a single-file application.

I hope you can give me a tip on what to look for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not obvious to me how Private set to True could come to a good end. 
 So try False.